# SQLAlchemy ORM ArgumentError with in_()

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Given the two following ORM classes:

```
class Indi(conn.pampas.Base):
    'SQLAlchemy class defining the pampas indi table.'

    __tablename__ = 'indi'
    __table_args__ = {'keep_existing': True}
    __module__ = 'pampas.sql.tables.pampas'

    cid_indicator_key = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(200), primary_key=True, nullable=False, doc='col_doc, primary_key=True, nullable=False)')
    cfl_active = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(1), nullable=False, doc='Column(String, nullable=False)')
    ctx_desc = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(200), nullable=False, doc='Column(String, nullable=False)')
    cfl_indicator_type = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(1), nullable=False, doc='Column(String, nullable=False)')
    nno_timeout = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer(), nullable=False, doc='Column(Integer, nullable=False)')
    ctx_tooltip = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(500), doc='Column(String, nullable=False)')
    ctx_hyperlink = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(2000), doc='Column(String, nullable=False)')

    def __repr__(self):
        'Returns repr(self).'

        fmt_str = "<{cls}({cid_indicator_key}={cid_indicator_key!r}, {cfl_active}={cfl_active!r}, {ctx_desc}={ctx_desc!r}, {cfl_indicator_type}={cfl_indicator_type!r}, {nno_timeout}={
nno_timeout!r}, {ctx_tooltip}={ctx_tooltip!r}, {ctx_hyperlink}={ctx_hyperlink!r})>"

        params = {
            'cls': type(self).__name__,
            'cid_indicator_key': self.cid_indicator_key,
            'cfl_active': self.cfl_active,
            'ctx_desc': self.ctx_desc,
            'cfl_indicator_type': self.cfl_indicator_type,
            'nno_timeout': self.nno_timeout,
            'ctx_tooltip': self.ctx_tooltip,
            'ctx_hyperlink': self.ctx_hyperlink,
        }

        return fmt_str.format(**params)

class IndiHierarchy(conn.pampas.Base):
    'SQLAlchemy class defining the pampas indi_hierarchy table.'

    __tablename__ = 'indi_hierarchy'
    __table_args__ = {'keep_existing': True}
    __module__ = 'pampas.sql.tables.pampas'

    cid_parent_indicator_key = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(200), sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('indi.cid_indicator_key'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, doc="col_doc, primary_key=T
rue, nullable=False, foreign_key='indi.cid_indicator_key')")
    cid_child_indicator_key = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(200), sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('indi.cid_indicator_key'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, doc="col_doc, primary_key=Tr
ue, nullable=False, foreign_key='indi.cid_indicator_key')")
    nno_seq_num = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer(), nullable=False, doc='Column(Integer, nullable=False)')
    cid_layout_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(200), doc='Column(String, nullable=False)')
    ctx_url_params = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(100), doc='Column(String, nullable=False)')
    cid_plugin_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(200), sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('plugin.plugin_id'), doc="Column(String, nullable=False, foreign_key='plugin.plugin_id')")
    ctx_created_by = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(1), nullable=False, doc='Column(String, nullable=False)')
    cid_plant = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(10), doc='Column(String, nullable=False)')
    cid_version = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Float(), nullable=False, server_default=sqlalchemy.schema.FetchedValue(), doc='Column(Float, nullable=False, server_default=FetchedValue
)')

    indi_child = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(("'Indi'",), backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('indi_hierarchy_child'), primaryjoin='IndiHierarchy.cid_child_indicator_key == Indi.cid_indica
tor_key')
    indi_parent = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(("'Indi'",), backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('indi_hierarchy_parent'), primaryjoin='IndiHierarchy.cid_parent_indicator_key == Indi.cid_ind
icator_key')
    plugin = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(("'Plugin'",), backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('indi_hierarchy'))

    def __repr__(self):
        'Returns repr(self).'

        fmt_str = "<{cls}({cid_parent_indicator_key}={cid_parent_indicator_key!r}, {cid_child_indicator_key}={cid_child_indicator_key!r}, {nno_seq_num}={nno_seq_num!r}, {cid_layout_id
}={cid_layout_id!r}, {ctx_url_params}={ctx_url_params!r}, {cid_plugin_id}={cid_plugin_id!r}, {ctx_created_by}={ctx_created_by!r}, {cid_plant}={cid_plant!r}, {cid_version}={cid_version
!r})>"

        params = {
            'cls': type(self).__name__,
            'cid_parent_indicator_key': self.cid_parent_indicator_key,
            'cid_child_indicator_key': self.cid_child_indicator_key,
            'nno_seq_num': self.nno_seq_num,
            'cid_layout_id': self.cid_layout_id,
            'ctx_url_params': self.ctx_url_params,
            'cid_plugin_id': self.cid_plugin_id,
            'ctx_created_by': self.ctx_created_by,
            'cid_plant': self.cid_plant,
            'cid_version': self.cid_version,
        }

        return fmt_str.format(**params)
```

I attempt the following query:

```
indi_upd_keys = ('W10_IPST_SERVERHEALTH_LOAD',)

with conn.pampas.session() as session:
    query2 = session.query(tables.pampas.Indi).filter(tables.pampas.Indi.cid_indicator_key.in_(indi_upd_keys))
    print(query2)
    print(session.execute(query2))
```

This causes the following error:

**ArgumentError: relationship 'indi_child' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'tuple'>)**

This appears to be caused because of my use of the `in_()` method. However, my use of `in_()` shouldn't cause this, right?

Is there some better way to accomplish what I need? I need to have the ability to match multiple potential values for the `cid_indicator_key` field. the `in_()` operator seemed correct for this. Am I wrong?

Or should I define my relationships differently? I know there are... *peculiarities* with using `backref`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel foolish, I see the problem.

```
indi_child = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(("'Indi'",), backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('indi_hierarchy_child'), primaryjoin='IndiHierarchy.cid_child_indicator_key == Indi.cid_indica
tor_key')
    indi_parent = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(("'Indi'",), backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('indi_hierarchy_parent'), primaryjoin='IndiHierarchy.cid_parent_indicator_key == Indi.cid_ind
icator_key')
    plugin = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(("'Plugin'",), backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('indi_hierarchy'))
```

should be:

```
indi_child = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Indi', backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('indi_hierarchy_child'), primaryjoin='IndiHierarchy.cid_child_indicator_key == Indi.cid_indica
tor_key')
    indi_parent = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Indi', backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('indi_hierarchy_parent'), primaryjoin='IndiHierarchy.cid_parent_indicator_key == Indi.cid_ind
icator_key')
    plugin = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Plugin', backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('indi_hierarchy'))
```